Can a person's age be automatically estimated based on hand gesture analysis?
Background
The Australian Government recently asked for submissions from the public regarding the Online Safety Amendment (Social Media Minimum Age) Bill 2024 which requires social media platforms to perform age-validation on users.
One of the submissions ([#7 of in this list of 107 submissions) was from the Age Verification Providers Association. They made the claim below, as part of their submission that technology is available to support the new legislation.
Claim

Hand gesture analysis – in a recent innovation, whether a user is over or under a certain age can be estimated with >99% accuracy based on three hand movements. This is due to the correlation of age with the operation of tendons in the hand.

It appears to be unreferenced to me.
Putting aside the question of whether 99% accuracy is sufficient, I find it hard to believe that children can pose for three hand gestures, and technology can accurately determine if they are over a certain age or not.
Has this been shown to be technically possible?

Even if it works with naïve subjects who have no incentive to influence the result, it would need to be shown to work on knowledgeable subjects who have an incentive to change the result. The gummi bear fingerprint fiasco is a cautionary tale here.

This seems to be relevant: https://www.biometricupdate.com/202409/biometrics-firms-pitch-privacy-in-age-assurance-ahead-of-us-court-battle It references a company called Needemand who make the same claims. At this point their website is being updated. https://www.needemand.com/

@PaulJohnson You can't just say "gummi bear fingerprint fiasco" and not tell us more.

@Schwern: https://www.theregister.com/2002/05/16/gummi_bears_defeat_fingerprint_sensors/

My father told me decades ago that in parts of (India?) where birth records were spotty, children started school when they could put their right arm up, bend it across the top of their head and then bend the wrist down and touch their left ear. Something about the relative size of heads and arm bones. It was considered accurate enough for "starting school" purposes so probably a year or less.

@Schwern Here is the first google hit on that which seems to match quite well: https://www.theregister.com/2002/05/16/gummi_bears_defeat_fingerprint_sensors/ It has also been observed by other organisations that a photograph of someones fingers with a professional camera can be sufficient to copy that persons fingerprints with similar techniques as described in the article.

@Oddthinking Ah, that. Mythbusters did it.

I've just been checking on the Wayback Machine. Needemand have had a placeholder page up since at least 21st May 2024, so its been a lot more than just a few days. https://web.archive.org/web/20240521172022/https://www.needemand.com/

@PaulJohnson: I think there is an answer waiting to be posted which is "Needemand had a 2023 prototype. It was much less accurate than these claims. The AVPA published in on their pages that Needemand did meet these claims - whether that was an error by AVPA, a false claim from Needemand, or because they suddenly got much better in a very short timeframe, I don't know. Needemand then stopped trading, and the technology never saw light of day." I don't have the French knowledge (and French government knowledge) to be able to support this with evidence, and therefore could well be wrong.

@KateGregory: that was IIRC part of the physical tests (among other things like walking backwards and hopping on one leg) for starting school as well in Germany mid of the 1980s. Despite having birth records. And vaccination leaflets. These tests  are done as a mix of medical screening and deciding whether a kid enters school at age 6 or 7 (or in rare cases, 5)


Putting aside the question of whether 99% accuracy is sufficient

OK, I'll ignore this.


I find it hard to believe that children can pose for three hand gestures

The law linked by OP defines "age-restricted user" as "an Australian child who has not reached 16 years." It's fine if age-restricted users cannot pose: they will be rejected as ineligible.  I'll consider accessibility concerns as out-of scope and won't address them in this answer.


technology can accurately determine if they are over a certain age or not.
Has this been shown to be technically possible?

I consider this to be OP's main question, so that's what I'll answer below.


Is this prone to deceptions?

OP didn't ask this question.  Even so, I'll briefly discuss it. However, this is more of a pragmatic/security issue than a skeptics.SE question.

Does this research exist?
The claim makes reference to a "recent innovation", so I'll guess that they're referencing some paper along the lines of the 2024 paper, Predicting human chronological age via AI analysis of dorsal hand versus facial images: A study in a cohort of Indian females.
I'm treating this particular paper as a representative paper, as it's the first one I found.  It's admittedly not the best choice:  It uses a dataset with participants aged 20-80 years whereas the proposed law is intended to provide a younger separator.
The research behind the paper was to use a computer to process images within a hand and face data sets.  Hence, there are likely to be numerous similar papers produced in a similar manner.

How could a hand photo be used to estimate age?
Quoting that paper:

As people age, the skin loses elasticity and becomes thinner, which
can cause wrinkles and creases to become more prominent. Moreover, it
can cause the veins and tendons on the dorsal side of the hand to
become more prominent, and the bones in the hand to become more
visible, including zones of the knuckles, phalanges and metacarpal
bones.

I'll take it for granted that the machine learning code trained by the authors found this or similar visible indicators of age.

What if the hand belongs to someone who is very close in age to the age limit
The machine learning system described above (and any similar system) will have estimation errors.  E.g., the authors note a mean error of 4.7 years (presumably the error range is proportional to age, so this isn't necessarily as bad as it sounds).  Due to such error, such a system is not very reliable in filtering out those who are close to the legal line. The submission authors acknowledge this concern:

Where estimation is used, there is a need to provide alternative methods to correct false negatives, for example when a 14 year-old has been estimated to look under 13 so is initially denied access to
social media (assuming 13 is the applicable minimum age).
...
But for the vast majority of people who are by definition more than +/- 2 years of any given minimum age, age estimation is a quick, convenient, privacy-preserving and effective method of age assurance.


Is deception a concern?
This is somewhat separate from OP's question.  Even so, I'll reply to Paul Johnson's comment that such a system might be vulnerable to deception: The technique discussed in the paper uses gestures as a means to expose physical characteristics to a camera.  I don't think this is necessarily any more prone to deception than using facial photographs and telling the subject to face in a particular direction (which are also prone to various forms of deception).
Nonetheless, barring some way to prevent it, deception is incredibly easy: The primary motivation for using hands rather than faces (which are, per the paper above, more reliable) is for privacy.  However, that privacy also makes it easier to cheat by just using someone else's hands.  Further, people are probably more willing assist in cheating such a system if it doesn't require them to leave behind a picture of their face as evidence.

Summary/Conclusion
The submission proposes to use hand pictures as an age estimation tool, specifically for those who are far enough outside the age requirement that such photos are reliable.  That is, those who multiple years older than the legal age requirement can use such photos as a means of estimating their age, thus bypassing other, more onerous (and less privacy-preserving) methods of age verification. The paper I found strongly suggests that hand photographs could be used for this purpose (ignoring the deception concerns raised by Paul Johnson).

I feel like the error margin is a big deal some of the most important demographic to identified are those one or two year under. most of those that should be denied access will be just one or two year younger that the treshold not five or ten.

@Bougainville: Keep in mind that the proposal was not to unconditionally use hand recognition as age identification.  Rather, the proposal was to allow hand recognition as a faster option in the case of users who are outside some predefined window.  Possibly the window suggested in the proposal (+/- 1-2 years) is too narrow, but that's an issue that will need to be evaluated if the proposal is accepted.  There are various knobs and dials that one can tweak to manage the trade-off between accurate results versus not marking users as ineligible to use this solution.

This is a classic security fiasco waiting to happen. Trivially easy to bypass, plus an accessibility and diversity nightmare! The accuracy depends on so many physiological and environmental assumptions. Plus AI is only as good as its training set and AI data sets tend to have biases. Sucks to be that (likely to be more than) 1% where it doesn't work and you have to give out your ID to everyone. And it's going to be the same (likely to be more than) 1% of people every time. Or it lets in "lucky" 15 year olds with arthritis. But it's cheap!!! Somebody's going to try it.

While this is good background research, unfortunately it fails to answer the OP's question: whether gesture analysis can be used for age verification. I agree, its pretty likely that any such analysis is going to have the same kind of error bars as this method, but its not by any means certain.

@PaulJohnson: The method is that the person positions their hand a certain way (i.e., makes a hand gesture), then a photo is taken of their hand in that particular position.  That's exactly what the referenced research is talking about.

@Brian The original claim was for "three hand movements", not a single still shot of a hand posed in a particular way.

@PaulJohnson I don't think the distinction between "hand gesture" and "hand movement" is significant. That wording comes from a letter aimed at politicians, not a research paper.

@Schwern - Not to mention that there is no evidence of testing against deception. Can the system be defeated by moving your hands like a old person? We don't know! Can it be defeated by AI apps that filter camera data to spoof images? We don't know! Can it be defeated by putting some oil on the camera, making the image blurry? We don't know! We certainly do know that it can be defeated by having some friends with older hands, so there is that.

When have legislators ever succeeded at preventing children from bypassing age verification systems online? Even if they could perfectly verify age at account creation, there would be many people disposed to sell and share accounts. They already tried and failed with COPPA in the USA two decades ago. The only conceivable ways to truly prevent most children from using social media would be so invasive as to require full control of everyone's computers, telescreen style, which I suspect might be unpopular with adults....
